# Runtime error 3032, cannot perform this operation ms-access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Unable to set value `on unload` to other forms field. If the field is unbound then the value set properly and when I set the filed control property in the form for the specific field then `unload` event unable to set value in the other form field says

> error 3032, cannot perform this operation.

`unload` event code below:

```
Dim oItem As Variant
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iCount As Integer

iCount = 0

If Me![SelectTenant].ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
    For Each oItem In Me![SelectTenant].ItemsSelected
        If iCount = 0 Then
            sTemp = sTemp & Me![SelectTenant].ItemData(oItem)
            iCount = iCount + 1
        Else
            sTemp = sTemp & mstrSep & " " & Me![SelectTenant].ItemData(oItem)
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
    Next oItem
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing was selected from the list", vbInformation
    Exit Sub  'Nothing was selected
End If

Forms!TenantAssign![Tenant].Value = sTemp
End Sub
```

Any help would much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates, that the field bound to `Forms!TenantAssign![Tenant]` cannot accept the *value* or *type* of `sTemp`.

Also note, that when you have corrected this and the code will run without an error, `Forms!TenantAssign` will be left *Dirty*.

Comment: what would be the reason to not accepting value? it's a simple text type field.

Comment: Can't tell. Perhaps the form as such is read-only. Try from the immediate window: `Forms!TenantAssign![Tenant].Value = "Test"`.

Comment: I tried from the immediate window, the same thing here

Comment: OK. Then, for sure, the issue is not related to your code but to the form _TenantAssign_.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure also but it's a simple form, I checked out that not read-only. Then what else!!??

Comment: Create a new form - as simple as possible - bound to the same table. It should work with your code line (tested here). If so, study the differences between the old form and the test, or simply recreate the old form step by step until failure.